# robot_localization package not subscribing to the wheel encoder topics or imu topics

Tags: ros2, robot-localization

I am building a mobile robot and I currently have wheel encoders publishing on a /odometry topic and an imu publishing on a /imu/data topic attached are the outputs of a topic echo for both can anyone see why the ekf node from robot_localzation wouldn't be subscribing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your RL configuration file point to subscribe to those topics of the right types?

Comment: @SteveMacenski yes here is what shows when i run ros2 topic list: 
/diagnostics
/imu/data
/odometry
/odometry/filtered
/parameter_events
/rosout
/set_pose
/tf
/tf_static
and in the ekf config file is:         odom0: /odometry &  imu0: /imu/data

Comment: Please paste any console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things...](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

Please include your full EKF config and sample message from each sensor input, but please do so as text, and not as images. You can use the code sample button to make it readable.

But right off the bat, it looks to me like your wheel encoder odometry has no `child_frame_id`. If you are trying to fuse velocity from your wheel encoders, you're going to need to fill that out. I recommend reading the `r_l` [documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html). The bit that's relevant (possibly) to you is:

> nav_msgs/Odometry - All pose data (position and orientation) is transformed from the message header’s frame_id into the coordinate frame specified by the world_frame parameter (typically map or odom). In the message itself, this specifically refers to everything contained within the pose property. All twist data (linear and angular velocity) is transformed from the child_frame_id of the message into the coordinate frame specified by the base_link_frame parameter (typically base_link).

But again, without the information I requested, it's impossible to really comment.